# Unable to forward with iptables

Tags: iptables

How can I forward traffic from a specific port to another machine?

```
+-----------------+     +----------------------+      +------------------------+
|     client      |     |   intermediary       |      |  server                |
|     (windows)   |     |    (debian)          |      |  (Windows)             |
|      10.10.1.30-+-----+-10.10.1.1 (eno1)     |      |                        |
+-----------------+     |   10.10.2.1 (ens6f3)-+------+-10.10.2.2 (port 3389)  |
                        +----------------------+      +------------------------+
```

In this test case, I am trying to RDP (TCP port 3389) from `client` to `server`.  I'm trying to set up `iptables` rules on the `intermediary`, but I'm failing to do so:

```
$ sudo sysctl -a
...
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 0
net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding = 0
net.ipv4.conf.eno1.forwarding = 0
net.ipv4.conf.ens6f3.forwarding = 0
...
$ sudo sysctl net.ipv4.conf.eno1.forwarding=1
$ sudo iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eno1 -p tcp --dport 3389 -j DNAT --to 10.10.2.2:3389
$ sudo iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -d 10.10.2.2 --dport 3389 -j ACCEPT
$ sudo iptables -t nat -L -n -v
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target  prot opt in    out   source           destination     
    0     0 DNAT    tcp  --  eno1  *     0.0.0.0/0        0.0.0.0/0     tcp dpt:3389 to 10.10.2.2:3389
```

I am now trying to RDP from 10.10.1.30 to 10.10.1.1.  I am expecting to log into 10.10.2.2, but I get no response from that port.

What am I doing wrong?

I've also tried:

```
$ sudo sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
$ sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i eno1 -o ens6f3 -p tcp --syn --dport 3389 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT 
$ sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i eno1 -o ens6f3 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
$ sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i ens6f3 -o en01 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: `INPUT` and `OUTPUT` chains are allowing the traffic?

Comment: `sudo ip tables -L INPUT` gives `Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)` with no further details. Similar output for `OUTPUT`.

Comment: Does your server know that the route back to the client (10.10.1.30) goes via 10.10.2.1?